# php make_time() and date() function

Tags: php, date, time, makefile

My system time is supposed to be `11.09 AM`. When I use the `date()` and `mktime()` functions, it shows different times like `05.00 AM`.

I am not getting it. Help me to get the correct system time.

Comment: In your php.ini find date.timezone and set it to your local timezone name

Comment: Use this server function  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` and see what you get..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust timezone before accessing the date. In php there's a function to set the timezone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");  //setting timezone
date("l, M-d-Y, H:i:s");
?>
```

Here's the list of all timezone

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

Check your timezone settings in `php.ini` or set something like this according to your local timezone support -

```
<?php

$timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

List of timezone supports and check accordingly -

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php